# proxy is working locally,But not with remote host

Tags: raspbian, networking, pi-3b+, server

I have install 3proxy in rapberrypi.Raspberrypi is connected with 4g dongle.My proxy is working fine in locally,but I can not connect it to remote host(Vps).It shows "Error: I could not see your service on 93.206.242.8 on port (8000)" in canyouseeme.org.If my pi is connected to home network,it works nicely with remote host.I have tried a lot to solve this problem ,but failed.Hopefully anyone can help me.Thank you.

Comment: the port is blocked by the 4g network provider - in my experience, **all** *incoming connections* are blocked on 4g networks

Comment: @Jaromanda X ,Thank you for your answer.Any solution for that?

Comment: I may have misread the question to be honest ... is `93.206.242.8` the pi on 4g?

Comment: Thank you.93.206.242.8 is  the external ip of huawei modem 4g connection.192.1681.65 is the internal ip of pi in my local network which is port forwarded to 8000.

Comment: yeah, so the 4g modem IP address is what the pi has - and what's the port forwarding? where is that done?

Comment: Pi is connected to 4g internet with wvdial and ppp0.I port forwarded 192.1681.65(Pi ip address) to 8000.Which is working locally.Whatsmyip says my external ip is 93.206.242.8.

Comment: `I port forwarded` where? on your home router? what does the 4G have to do with any of that? your 4G dongle isn't connected to your home router, so port forwarding on the home router wont do jack with your 4G

Comment: Yes.I port forwarded in my home router.

Comment: @JaromandaX I don't have that much knowledge about networking stuffs.I tried a lot,but failed.So if I want to make it working,then I have to port forward in my 4g modem network.Suggest me some solution please.Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you considered that all incoming connections on 4g networks **may** be blocked by the 4g network provider?

Comment: @JaromandaX,I have talked with them.There are not blocking all connection.