# Raspberry pi port forwarding issue

Tags: raspbian, networking, pi-3b+, port-forwarding

I have a raspberrypi which is raspbian installed.I am connecting rpi with ssh via my home wifi.Then Installed 3proxy,usb modeswitch and wvdial.And my 4g wifi dongle is connected and up.This my config:

```
eth0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether b8:27:eb:cf:88:9b  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 708  bytes 46694 (45.5 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 708  bytes 46694 (45.5 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

ppp0: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 100.96.79.106  netmask 255.255.255.255  destination 10.64.64.64
        ppp  txqueuelen 3  (Point-to-Point Protocol)
        RX packets 6  bytes 66 (66.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 7  bytes 129 (129.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.86  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::f94:92ee:a81d:cb32  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether b8:27:eb:9a:dd:ce  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 617993  bytes 129120683 (123.1 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 1  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 404244  bytes 77427635 (73.8 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wwan0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 169.254.12.137  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 169.254.255.255
        inet6 fe80::843d:9de5:aefa:f853  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:1e:10:1f:00:00  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1421  bytes 536440 (523.8 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

After that I port forwarded it in my home router which is 192.168.1.86:3129.But proxy is working nice in my laptop,but not in vps.Did I do something wrong in port forwarding matter.Do I need to do do in my home router or in my 4g dongle.Please give me a solution.

**Update** from comment:
My problem is my proxy is not working remotely and its about proxy and port forwarding.Vps is virtual private server.First I connect rpi via ssh with home router.So at first point its connected with my home router.Then with wvdial and with some command I made ppp0 (which is my 4g dongle network) as a default route.So my rpi is now in 4g network.Then I port forwarded my rpi ip(192.168.1.86) to 3129 which listening my proxy port in raspberry pi.3proxy (a proxy server ) is installed in RPI and its listening 3129 port.So my proxy(192.168.1.86:3129)working nice in browser but not remotely.

Comment: What is the problem? Proxy or port forwarding? What is "3proxy,usb"? What is "vps"? What connection do you use to connect to the internet, home router or 4g dongle? For what do you need port forwarding? What program on the RasPi is serving port 3129? Please address me with @Ingo, otherwise it may be possible that I don't see your reply.

Comment: @Ingo ,My problem is my proxy is not working remotely and its about proxy and port forwarding.Vps is virtual private server.First I connect rpi via ssh with home router.So at first point its connected with my home router.Then with wvdial and with some command I made ppp0 (which is my 4g dongle network) as a default route.So my rpi is now in  4g network.Then I  port forwarded my rpi ip(192.168.1.86) to 3129 which listening my proxy port in raspberry pi.3proxy (a proxy server ) is installed in RPI and its listening 3129 port.So my proxy(192.168.1.86:3129)working nice in browser but not remotely.

Comment: I'm sure I've read the question before just in the last couple of days

Comment: @JaromandaX,this is my first post.

Comment: I'm sure it is, someone posted something very similar earlier in the week, I was hoping to find it in case there was an answer that could help you - but the question is gone

Comment: Are you trying to make an incoming connection to the 4G address?

Comment: @JaromandaX,I am trying to  make an incoming connection to the 4G address.Yes.

Comment: In my experience (in Australia) mobile providers (i.e. 4G) block all incoming connections - by the way, I've found the question https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/96487/proxy-is-working-locally-but-not-with-remote-host

Comment: I saw this before also.There is no solution of my problem there sadly.

Comment: So, first step is to determine if that is the case - can you make an incoming connection to the 4G IP address - https://canyouseeme.org/ could help

Comment: No,It says I could not see your service in port 3129.